# Class groups containing only elements of odd order

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I need to find an  infinite number of real quadratic fields such that their class groups contain only elements of odd order. Is it true for all real quadratic fields with prime discriminant?

Can we find *all* real quadratic fields such that their class groups contain only elements of odd order?